# key value coding compliant error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to rewrite several parts of the code so that it is all programatically, without using a nib file. However after doing so I got the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<CvoreAppDelegate 0x503f380> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key rootViewController.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

This is actually called even before the applicationDidFinishLaunching is called.
Why is this? And how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you still have a nib file in your project, which has an outlet connection to `rootViewController`. Remove the connection.

Comment: I did remove reference the MainWindow.xib from the project, isn't this enough?

Comment: You should clean the project and rebuild it. You might also need to remove the app from the device or the simulator. You also need to remove a key from the Info.plist.  Anyway there's no good reason to remove the xib completely...